# Core Plot Bar Problems

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, core-plot

I want to fix the width of bar and whenever bar data changes dynamically barwidth should be fixed.But Its not working.And Second thing I want to get bar frame or exact position of particular bar.But not found any method till now.

So Please tell me if you know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates` to YES. This makes the plot interpret the bar width in pixels rather than as a fraction of the data units.

You can use the plot space to convert back and forth between data coordinates and view coordinates (pixels).